# What is the expected value of $\bar\beta=(Y_4-Y_1)/(X_4-X_1)$ under GM assumptions?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

In other words, is $\bar\beta$ an unbiased estimator? Suppose that original regression is specified as following $Y_i=\beta_1 X_i+u_i$.

Also, I would be happy to learn whether the existence of the constant term in the regression would have changed the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If, so please mark this as self-study and indicate what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is this for some class, study textbook exercise or similar?  What does "GM" stand for in this context?

Comment: If you only had two points for a linear regression, then clearly you would draw the line joining them, and the Gauss-Markov theorem would tell you that the line was the  best linear unbiased estimator of the coefficients, including the slope.  This would stop be the *best* if there are more points which you have ignored, but would still be *unbiased*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming in your notation that the $u_i$ is the error term of the $i$th observation.  In that case, under the Gauss-Markov model:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[Y_{i}\right] & = & E\left[\beta_{1}X_{i}+u_{i}\right]\\
 & = & \beta_{1}X_{i}+E[u_{i}]\,(\mbox{Since}\,X_{i}\mbox{ is a constant})\\
 & = & \beta_{1}X_{i}+0\\
 & = & \beta_{1}X_{i}
\end{eqnarray*}

So,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\bar{\beta}\right] & = & E\left[\frac{Y_{4}-Y_{1}}{X_{4}-X_{1}}\right]\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{X_{4}-X_{1}}\right)E\left[Y_{4}-Y_{1}\right]\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{X_{4}-X_{1}}\right)\left(E\left[Y_{4}\right]-E\left[Y_{1}\right]\right)\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{X_{4}-X_{1}}\right)\left(\beta_{1}X_{4}-\beta_{1}X_{1}\right)\\
 & = & \left(\frac{\beta_{1}}{X_{4}-X_{1}}\right)\left(X_{4}-X_{1}\right)\\
 & = & \beta_{1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Note that the Gauss-Markov model says nothing about normality (I just figured I'd make this comment since you tagged "Normal-distribution").

Comment: Now, let's apply Rao-Blackwell to that...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question from an assignment or a text book and GM stands for Gauss-Markov assumptions.

Anyway, here is the solution I come up with. So, maybe you can at least tell me whether it is correct or not.

\begin{align}
\bar \beta &= \frac{(\beta_1 X_4-u_4)-(\beta_1 X_1-u_1)}{ X_4-X_1}  \\[7pt]
\bar \beta &= \frac{\beta_1(X_4-X_1)+( u_4-u_1)}{ X_4-X_1}  \\[7pt]
\bar \beta &= \beta_1+\frac{( u_4-u_1)}{ X_4-X_1}  \\[7pt]
E(\bar \beta) &= E\Bigg(\beta_1+\frac{( u_4-u_1)}{ X_4-X_1}\Bigg)  \\[7pt]
E(\bar \beta) &= \beta_1+E\Bigg(\frac{( u_4-u_1)}{ X_4-X_1}\Bigg)  \\[7pt]
E(u_i) &= 0   
\end{align}

(this is where gauss-markov assumption "kicks in" as I believe)

$E(\bar \beta)=\beta_1$; therefore $E(\bar \beta)$ turns out to be an unbiased estimator.

Comment: This is not correct.  I'm not even sure what $\beta$ is in your solution.  See my solution provided above for complete details.